# onPagescrolled called multiple times

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, touch

I'm having an onPageScrolled method in my android app code which is being called multiple times when scrolled once, why is this happening ?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use onPageSelected?